# Buildroot Rootfs with XOrg doesn't show GUI

Tags: xorg, qemu, buildroot

I have built a rootfs using buildroot using template of `qemu_x86_64_defconfig` and adding XOrg server configuration on top of it.
To start the system, I am using script generated by buildroot to invoke qemu. `output/images/start-qemu.sh`

On the boot messages, I can see the XOrg is started but when I executed xcalc, it resulted in

```
Error: Can't open display:
```

Here is xdm.log

```
xdm info (pid 114): Starting xdm 1.1.12
xdm info (pid 114): Starting X server on :0
(EE)
Fatal server error:
(EE) Server is already active for display 0
        If this server is no longer running, remove /tmp/.X0-lock
        and start again.
(EE)
(EE)
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support
         at http://wiki.x.org
 for help.
(EE)
xdm error (pid 114): server unexpectedly died
xdm error (pid 114): Server for display :0 can't be started, session disabled
xdm info (pid 114): Exiting
```

In Xorg.0.0.log

```
[     2.871] (II) modeset(0): Setting screen physical size to 270 x 203                                                             
[     3.136] (II) Using input driver 'mouse' for '<default pointer>'                                                                
[     3.137] (**) Option "CorePointer" "on"                                                                                         
[     3.137] (**) <default pointer>: always reports core events                                                                     
[     3.137] (WW) <default pointer>: No Device specified, looking for one...                                                        
**[     3.138] (EE) <default pointer>: Cannot find which device to use.**                                                               
[     3.138] (==) <default pointer>: Protocol: "Auto"                                                                               
[     3.138] (**) <default pointer>: always reports core events                                                                     
[     3.138] (EE) xf86OpenSerial: No Device specified.                                                                              
[     3.138] (WW) <default pointer>: cannot open input device                                                                       
[     3.138] (==) <default pointer>: Emulate3Buttons, Emulate3Timeout: 50                                                           
[     3.139] (**) <default pointer>: ZAxisMapping: buttons 4 and 5                                                                  
[     3.139] (**) <default pointer>: Buttons: 9                                                                                     
[     3.139] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "<default pointer>" (type: MOUSE, id 6)                                      
[     3.140] (**) <default pointer>: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1                                                          
[     3.141] (**) <default pointer>: (accel) acceleration profile 0                                                                 
[     3.141] (**) <default pointer>: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000                                                             
[     3.141] (**) <default pointer>: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4                                                              
**[     3.141] (EE) xf86OpenSerial: No Device specified.**                                                                              
[     3.141] (WW) <default pointer>: cannot open input device                                                                       
[     3.142] (II) Using input driver 'kbd' for '<default keyboard>'                                                                 
[     3.142] (**) Option "CoreKeyboard" "on"
```

What is going wrong here?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to the U&L stack exchange. To help the community answer your question, we will need more information. Please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/612487/edit) your question and add any logs related to qemu along with the exact command you're running with the output

Answer (score 1):

The error message is generated by the programming language equivalent of this shell script command:

```
echo "Can't open display: $DISPLAY" >&2
```

So the fact that you don't see anything after the second colon means the `DISPLAY` environment variable was not set (or was set to a null value).

When starting a X11 server, a session cookie is also generated (unless X11 authentication is disabled, which is not secure). You must have something that passes a copy of this cookie to the user executing X11 applications: the cookie is normally placed either in a file pointed to by the `XAUTHORITY` environment variable, or if such variable is not defined, to `~/.Xauthority` file in the user's home directory.

This is why starting the X11 server is normally handled by a special program: either `startx` (which is a script using a low-level tool `xinit`) if you intend to fire up a X11 session for a user that's already logged in locally in text mode, or a X Display Manager (typically named `*dm`, e.g. `gdm`, `sddm`, `xdm`) which will initially present a GUI login prompt and then process the user login.

In both cases, the special program will handle starting both the X11 server and the first GUI application using the server, so the program can hand the appropriate environment settings to the application process. Any child processes of the first application will automatically inherit the environment variables.

(The X11 session setup can and often will do quite a bit more than that, but that's the absolute minimum it needs to do.)